# Encode first order constructive logic in sets

Tags: set-theory, foundations

I've been mechanizing some set theory (IZF).

I want to experiment with encoding a fragment of first order constructive logic in terms of sets and define separation in terms of simpler primitives.

I think you want something like

$$ \{ x \in e \mid P \} = \{ \{ x \mid y \in [P] \} \mid x \in e \}$$

$$ \begin{align*}
[\bot] = & \emptyset \\
[\top] = & \{ \emptyset \}\\
[P \vee Q] = & [P]\cup [Q] \\
[P \wedge Q] = & \{ [P] \mid x \in [Q] \}\\
[P \rightarrow Q] = &[\{(x, [\top]) \mid x \in [P]\} = \{ (x, [Q]) \mid x \in [P] \}] & \\
[\exists x\in e. P] = & \{ [P] \mid x \in e \} \\
[\forall x\in e. P] = & [\{(x, [\top]) \mid x \in e\} = \{ (x, [P]) \mid x \in e \}]\\
[e_1 = e_2] = & [ e_1 \in \{ e_2 \} ]\\
[ e_1 \in e_2] = & ?
\end{align*}$$

Some of the details feel very unclear to me and I'm not sure how wanting constructive logic changes things.

I think you can pretty much always do Goedel sentences but that's kind of a sledgehammer and wouldn't be nice at all in a theorem prover.

I'm sure there must be a standard sort of way to do this coding in the literature?

Comment: So a less ad-hoc way of doing this might be too define the Cartesian product, dependent sum and dependent product and code in terms of those. $A \wedge B = [A] \times [B]$ $\exists x \in e. P(x) = \Sigma_{x \in e} [P(x)]$ etc...  Set of functions is hard though. Not sure if it's possible without a subset of total functional relations

Comment: Think I might have to assume at least inverse image. Kind of cheating though

Comment: I don't understand the equality $[\{(x, [\top]) \mid x \in e\} = \{ (x, [P]) \mid x \in e \}]$, is $[Q]$ necessarily some set where that equality holds?